# Inverse of matrix transformations

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

Functions $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ are called transformations from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$.

A transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ has an inverse if there is some transformation $S$ such that $T\circ S=S\circ T=1_{\mathbb{R}^n}$.

Let $T=T_A:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ denote the matrix transformation induced by the $n \times n$ matrix $A$, that is, $T(\mathbf{x})=A\mathbf{x}$.

---

Statement: If $T$ has an inverse, then its matrix $A$ must be invertible. Also, $(T_A)^{-1}=T_{A^{-1}}$

Textbook proof (with minor changes to the wording):

"Indeed, suppose $S:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is any inverse of $T$, so that $S\circ T=1_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ and $T\circ S=1_{\mathbb{R}^n}$. If $B$ is the matrix of $S$, we have 
$$BA\mathbf{x}=S[T(\mathbf{x})]=(S\circ T)\mathbf{x}=1_{\mathbb{R^n}}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x}=I_n\mathbf{x}$$
It follows (by a previous theorem) that $BA=I_n$, and a similar argument shows that $AB=I_n$. Hence $A$ is invertible with $A^{-1}=B$. Furthermore, the inverse transformation $S$ has matrix $A^{-1}$, so $S=T_{A^{-1}}$ using the earlier notation."

My question is, how do we know that $S$ must be induced by some matrix $B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $S$ is induced by a matrix because it is linear. After all, since $T$ has an inverse it must be bijective, so for all $a,b$ and some $c,d$ we have $$S(a+b)=S(T(c)+T(d))=S(T(c+d))=c+d=S(a)+S(b)$$ and for all $\lambda\in \Bbb R$, $$S(\lambda a)=S(\lambda T(c))=S(T(\lambda c))=\lambda c=\lambda S(a)$$.

Your proof seems good as well.

Answer (score 0):

I come up with a different proof as below.

When $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$, 
$$\mathbf{x}=1_\mathbb{R^n}(\mathbf{x})=(S\circ T)(\mathbf{x})=S(A\mathbf{x})=S(\mathbf{0})=S(A\mathbf{0})=1_\mathbb{R^n}(\mathbf{0})=\mathbf{0}$$

By Inverse Theorem, $A$ is invertible, and the system $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{y}$ has at least one solution $\mathbf{x}$ for every choice of column $\mathbf{y}$. Now for any $\mathbf{y}\in \mathbb{R^n}$ ,
$$S(\mathbf{y})=S(A\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x}=A^{-1}A\mathbf{x}=A^{-1}\mathbf{y}$$

This shows that $S=T_{A^{-1}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Define the j-th column of $B$ by $S(e_j)$ for $j=1,2...3$ , where $e_j$'s are standard bases for $R^n$.

then observe that $S(x)=Bx$ for all $x \in R^n$

Comment: As $S$ is linear, $S(x)=\sum x_j S(e_j)=Bx$. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @delt Yes,   this is same as what I wrote in last line. So $S$ is indeed induced by a matrix(the answer of your question.)